# Counting distinct values from JSON using D3.nest()

Tags: d3.js

I have a following JSON:

```
{  
   "ReturnCode":0,
   "ReturnMessage":"Success",
   "List":[{  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"DP",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"4940"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"SP",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"4940"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"212355",
         "ProjectName":"45ed"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"212355",
         "ProjectName":"45ed "
      }, {  
         "Client":"we",
         "Department":" SP ",
         "ProjectId":"123455",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"we",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"123455",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"oc",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"24355",
         "ProjectName":"qwe"
   }]
}
```

I just need to count the number of projects to each client like below using d3.nest:

```
[{Key:”Ad”, value:2}, {Key:”we”, value:1}, {Key:”oc”, value:1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [d3.nest()](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) link it has many examples for rolling up for d3.nest() function. For your case you can do something like code written below.

```
d3.json("json/data.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Client; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.ProjectId; })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
    .entries(data.List);

    console.log(nested_data);

    console.log(nested_data[0].values.length) //length of key 'AD'
})
```

Comment: for the last part i would simply use ----               for (var item in nested_data) {

                            console.log(nested_data[item].key+'--'+ Object.keys(nested_data[item].values).length);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```js
var obj = {  
   "ReturnCode":0,
   "ReturnMessage":"Success",
   "List":[{  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"DP",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"4940"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"SP",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"4940"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"12355",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"212355",
         "ProjectName":"45ed"
      }, {  
         "Client":"Ad",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"212355",
         "ProjectName":"45ed "
      }, {  
         "Client":"we",
         "Department":" SP ",
         "ProjectId":"123455",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"we",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"123455",
         "ProjectName":"asdf"
      }, {  
         "Client":"oc",
         "Department":"Co",
         "ProjectId":"24355",
         "ProjectName":"qwe"
   }]
};

var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.Client; })
.key(function(d) { return d.ProjectId; })
.rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
.entries(obj.List)
.map(function(d){ 
  var ob = {};  
  ob.Key = d.key;
  ob.value = d.values.length; 
  return ob; 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(nested_data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
[{
    "Key": "Ad",
    "value": 2
}, {
    "Key": "we",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "Key": "oc",
    "value": 1
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

for the last part i would simply use ----

```
for (var item in nested_data) {
console.log(nested_data[item].key+'--'+ Object.keys(nested_data[item].values).length);
                        }
```